# Set default folder when print to a PDF-file

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-xe, fastreport

I am using FastReport printdialog.

I print to a PDF-file.
How can I set the initial folder that is suggested when I save the PDF-file ?

[image: Print dialog]
[image: Save file dialog]

Comment: Keep in mind that the "Save as" dialog only exists because of what you chose as printer (and "Microsoft Print to PDF" might not be the only one doing so and not even exist as per client).

Comment: Can you use the TfrxPDFExport component.  If so, you could set frxPDFExport.DefaultPath.  I use that in a program I wrote and I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to select the folder. But you can specify the full path like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    PrtIndex   : Integer;
    DeviceMode : THandle;
    Device,
    Driver,
    Port       : array [0..255] of Char;
begin
    // Warning: The printer name is case sensitive
    PrtIndex := Printer.Printers.IndexOf('Microsoft Print to PDF');
    if PrtIndex < 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Printer not found');
    Printer.PrinterIndex := PrtIndex;
    Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DeviceMode);
    Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, 'C:\Temp\TestPrintToPdf.pdf', 0);
    Printer.BeginDoc;
    Printer.Canvas.TextOut(100, 100, 'Hello World');
    Printer.EndDoc;
end;
```

You can add your own dialog box to ask the file name to the user and to select printing options.